# GMap.NET question

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gmap.net

i am trying to use GMap.NET to display a map using the following code

```
GMapControl g = new GMapControl();
GMap.NET.GMaps.Instance.Mode = GMap.NET.AccessMode.ServerOnly;
g.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
pnlMap.Controls.Add(g);
g.MapType = MapType.GoogleMap;
g.MaxZoom = 6;
g.MinZoom = 1;
g.Position = new PointLatLng(51.31835, 0.873866);
```

The issue is, the control loads but there is no visible map inside. Does anyone know what i might need to do

Thanks

edit:

the fix was this

```
  public Form1()
  {
     InitializeComponent();

     SuspendLayout();  
     GMapControl MainMap = new GMapControl();
     {
        MainMap.MapProvider = GMapProviders.YahooMap;
        MainMap.Position = new PointLatLng(54.6961334816182, 25.2985095977783);
        MainMap.MinZoom = 1;
        MainMap.MaxZoom = 17;
        MainMap.Zoom = 9;
        MainMap.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
     }
     Controls.Add(MainMap); 
     ResumeLayout(true);
  }
```